# Is there any best JIRA server plugin/app for maintaining and managing cucumber feature files?

Tags: cucumber, jira, gherkin

Is there any best JIRA server plugin/app for maintaining and managing cucumber feature files? There are few JIRA plugins like 'Cucumber for Jira - BDD natively in Jira', but they are for JIRA cloud. My need is for JIRA server and not data center. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We had a look at a couple and chose AssertThat.  Clean interface and easy to use.   Both are on cloud DC and Server.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219033/assertthat-bdd-cucumber-for-jira?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview

In terms of comparison between tools

| A header | AssertThat | BehavePro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ease of use and interface | 9 | 6 |
| Integrations / API's | yes | yes |
| Manual execution features | 8 | 5 |
| Import automated results | yes | No |